# Android - Creating BottomBar

Tags: android, android-layout

I want create a bottom bar just like that of the new google keep.

[Click here for screenshot](http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/nexus2cee_Screenshot_2015-07-22-13-58-45-329x585.png)

How to create a bottom bar like this. Is there any library available?
When I search for this in google, I get the result for bottom navigation view and that's not what I want

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
Wrap your bottomNavigationView in a LinearLayout, and add a editText besides it.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Of course give it some style to make it look better.

On your activity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    private BottomNavigationView navigation;
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.first_item:
                    //Do your stuff
                    return true;
                case R.id.second_item:
                    //Do your stuff
                    return true;
                case R.id.third_item:
                    //Do your stuff
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };
    ...
}
```

Finally on your menu res folder
navigation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/first_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_news_on"
        android:title="@string/first_title" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/second_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_statistics_on"
        android:title="@string/second_title" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/third_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_prizes_on"
        android:title="@string/third_title" />
</menu>
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: You can give the behavior you want to the BottomNavigationBar on your activity, no just navigate :) I will update my answer with the listner on the activity.